# Auto-increment primary key variable despite a natural composite key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

My central table is a table to identify all products in the catalogue. Feeding into this I have small 'characteristics' tables (Year/Manufacturer/Owner/Quality/length/width/height/weight etc). Each of which feed in allowable values (which may grow over time).

My problem is that I am using these variables as a composite primary key on these 'characteristics' tables. However:

1. Ideally some records should allow some null values for year
2. As this catalogue table is referenced in subsequent tables it would
   seem clearer to create a new auto-incrementing primary key variable
   so I can link tables on this one variable rather than joining on a
   compound of 8 variables and carrying these variables over to the
   other tables (one big INT variable compared to a mix of small/medium
   INT variables)
3. Can I (or should I?!) make a composite key with one auto
   incrementing big INT ID variable in combination with the 'year'
   variable (there could only be one occurrence of missing per bigint
   value so I could assign that 'year' to 0 for example)

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? MySQL? Which engine? InnoDB or MyISAM (if MySQL)?

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to knowing what background info I need to include(!)

Comment: I'm using MySQL with InnoDB engine

Comment: This is unclear. Give a schema with candidate keys and foreign keys and some description of when a row is in a table. If you have a characteristics table with column Year why would you need NULL or 0 instead of just no row? If central Id identifies a product, what does central Id + Year identify?